# How can solve IE8 prototype and fn issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a big problem with jquery.fn and prototype in IE8. I write a simple jquery library like this in demo.js file:

```
 (function(){
    Demo = function(){
        return new DemoLibrary();
    };
    function initAjaxError(){
      $(document).ajaxError(function(e, request, settings){
        switch (request.status) {
           case 400:
             var msg = $.parseJSON(request.getResponseHeader('message'));
             console.log(msg.message);
             break;
                default:
                case 403:
                    console.log('Access denied!');
                    break;
            }
        }); 
    }
    var DemoLibrary = function(){
        initAjaxError();
    };
    DemoLibrary.prototype = {
        prepareBody: function(){
           $('body').find('h1').css('font-size','72px');
        },
    };
    window.Test = window.$$ = demo = Demo();
    $$.fn = Object.getPrototypeOf(demo);
}());
```

And then write some code for coloring plugin in plugin.js :

```
(function(){
    $$.fn.coloring ={
        setColor : function(hexValue,selector){
            $('body').find($(selector)).css('color','#'+hexValue);
       }
    };
}());
```

At the end, I load this files with jquery-1.11.2.min.js in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
       <script src="demo.js"></script>
       <script src="plugin.js"></script>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $$.prepareBody();
            $$.coloring.setColor('ff0000', 'p');
         })
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
           <h1>This is h1 heading tag</h1>
           <p>this is a paragraph</p>
           <div>this  is a div paragraph</div>
           <h3><p>this is another paragraph</p></h3>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It's working perfectly in Firefox,Chrome and IE9 and higher,But in IE8 has some errors,first error says:

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method" in demo.js line 30
```

line 30 :

```
$$.fn = Object.getPrototypeOf(demo);
```

and other errors are :

```
'$$.fn' is null or not an object
```

in plugin.js line 2 and another error :

```
'$$.coloring' is null or not an object
```

in index.html line 11.
Finaly, I add prototype.js file after jquery library and before demo.js :

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="demo.js"></script>
<script src="plugin.js"></script>
```

I placed this script in prototype.js :

```
if ( typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function" ){
    (function(){
        function getPrototypeValue( o, p ) {
            if ( o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                var ownValue = o[ p ];
                if ( delete o[ p ] ) {
                    var prototypeValue = o[ p ];
                    o[p] = ownValue;
                    return prototypeValue;
                } else {
                    return o[p];
                }
            } else{
                return o[p];
            }
        }
        if (typeof "".proto === "object" ){
            Object.getPrototypeOf = function( object ) {
                return getPrototypeValue( object, 'proto' );
            };
        }else{
            Object.getPrototypeOf = function( object ) {
                getPrototypeValue( object, 'constructor' ).prototype;
            };
        }
    }());
}
```

Now, These erors not solved yet :

```
'$$.fn' is null or not an object
```

in plugin.js line 2 and another error :

```
'$$.coloring' is null or not an object
```

in index.html line 11.

I'm very worry about my work. Enybody can rescue me?

Comment: your getPrototypeOf function in the else block isnt doing a return

Comment: You have the reference to the prototype, why don't you just set it directly instead of trying to look it up?

Comment: And here I thought IE was finally dead. Sigh. Looks like the [Kogan Tax](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/06/kogan-imposing-tax-on-shoppers-who-use-ie7/) needs to be extended.